# How to save a randonly generated image with Python?

Tags: python, php, image, parsing, captcha

I'm trying to solve a CAPTCHA on a [website](https://www.list-org.com/bot).

< img src="/kcap.php?PHPSESSID=iahvgmjcb93a0k7fqrf43sq9sk" >

Html-code contains a redirect to php-generated img. But, if i try to follow this [link](https://www.list-org.com/kcap.php?PHPSESSID=iahvgmjcb93a0k7fqrf43sq9sk), the php generates a new image and the CAPTCHA solution fails.

I need to save this image by jpg. The image should not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image changing is being done at the server side, if you need a copy of this image you will need to save the image at the point of the page loading.

Looking at the data these images are JPEG's, this will download the image from that link,

```py
import urllib.request

local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.list-org.com/kcap.php?PHPSESSID=iahvgmjcb93a0k7fqrf43sq9sk")

print(local_filename)
```

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Are you able to provide some more information on what you are trying to do? Do you need to do anything with the page after getting the image?

Comment: I need to save a specific image to the variable (.jpg) to work with later. For example, send it to a resource that solves captcha automatically

Comment: The point of captcha's is for them to not be solved automatically.

Comment: Some resources offer a captcha solution with the help of people. I put it wrong when I said that the solution is automatic.

Comment: So, if I save the solution you gave to a variable, the variable will store .jpg-image?

Comment: urlretrieve saves the file locally (can't change once it is on your machine), it will output a filename in the form, local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve

Comment: When I print() the variable in which I saved this piece of code, I got ('local-filename.jpg', <http. client. HTTP Message object at 0x00000278D149F8B0>). How do I get out of this the .jpg file?

Comment: @Tohak I have made an edit to my answer to output the file path