# How to save a randonly generated image with Python (part two)?

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests, urllib, auto-generate

I ask this question again, because the previous solution does not work.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634431/how-to-save-a-randonly-generated-image-with-python) is my last question, it contains all the information about the task.

The main problem is that the solution suggested by [User1010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8458712/user1010) is based on using this PHPSESSID, but when I go to the link (the link is made up of "https://www.list-org.com" + PHPSESSID) a new image is generated.

```
<img src="/kcap.php?PHPSESSID=iahvgmjcb93a0k7fqrf43sq9sk">
```

Now the question itself. How do I save a specific image that is loaded with the site page?

Comment: Can you make screenshot instead of saving image?

Comment: I need to do this automatically.

Comment: You can interact with website and take screenshots automatically with Selenuim

Comment: Omg, it's working. Many thanks you so much for this advice!